# Better to have separate resource or different responses in REST

Tags: json, rest

Assume I have "shape" as a resource. I have 2 shapes one 'square' with ID 123, and  'circle' with ID 456.

```
So when i do a GET on the 123 I will get a response : v1/foo/shapes/123
{
  "id": "123",
  "type": "square",
  "side-lenght" : "6",
  "area" : "36"
}
When i do a GET on 456 i will get a response : v1/foo/shapes/456
{
  "id": "456",
  "type": "circle",
  "radius" : "7",
  "area" : "154"
}
```

Is it better to send different responses based on the type,
   (or)
Should i have 2 different types of resources altogether, having separate URI's such as 
`v1/foo/shapes/squares/123`, and `v1/foo/shapes/circles/456`, so that the client does not have to parse the response based on the "type" in the response.

Comment: It's a matter of taste really. Nothing stops you from having both by the way. You can just let the client decide how to pass the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

If the type of shape is necessarily part of its unique identifier, then it should be part of the URL. But if the `id` is sufficient to identify any shape, regardless of which shape it is, then I would say **do not** put the type of shape in the URL.

When asking for a particular shape, I shouldn't have to name particular attributes of it, if those attributes aren't needed to identify it.

Comment: Since the response for square and circle will have different parameters (and some common ones), a 'type' would be needed in the response for the client to parse it appropriately. So it is indeed needed in the response.

Comment: @sud Yes, you would still put the type of shape in the response. Nothing wrong with that. I was talking only about the URL for the resource.

Answer (score 0):

There is no formal standard on this and either approach is acceptable. REST does not dictate the granularity of the URL structure and cares instead about the verbs.

Answer (score 0):

The client needs to know how to parse the returned data one way or the other. It is just a matter of where in the execution flow (or abstraction level) the client code starts to be aware of the shapes.

The answer to your question will depend on if there is a use-case to partition the 'shapes' space into sub-spaces like squares, circles, and etc.

If there is no such need, you should go with just '/shapes/id'.  If you need that later, you can always add that. The APIs will still be working properly if you keep the returned data with the type in it.

Design just 'enough' to solve the problem first as long as it does not prevent you from extending it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the same URL structure but return different content, then should leverage the 'uniform interface' and specify that your content is different by using a different Content-Type header in your response depending on the type of content returned.

Alternately, you might use a [profile](http://www.mnot.net/blog/2012/04/17/profiles) to specify this same difference.